# Where I can post a supplementary video for my published paper?

Tags: publications, online-publication, repository, supporting-information

I have a paper submitted and accepted in a journal (Biology and Environmental Sciences) and it has a supplementary file which is a short video coverage, however, the journal does not support this but I have uploaded the video to Vimeo. Do you have any suggestions where I can store the video and generate a DOI (like other journals) then attach it to my paper?

Comment: I'm not sure you can have doi for that kind of media. Do you have personal website? You might consider putting the video there.

Comment: Discuss this with your local librarian.

Comment: You can't generate the DOI just like that. It has to be published after peer review by a journal. Otherwise, the best place is the personal/institutional web page. and give a link to your publication in a video frame itself.

Comment: No DOI, but Vimeo should be fine.  If you put it there, it may be around longer than your current personal web site.

Comment: @Coder actually, any organisation that meets the contractual obligations of the DOI system and is willing to pay to become a member of the system can assign DOIs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). It doesn't indicate peer review.

Comment: Keep in mind that most people will google it (name of the paper, maybe part of author's name + video), especially when showing it to other people. Most of the time, the actual place the video is doesn't really matter that much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Videos [are among the file types](https://support.figshare.com/support/solutions/articles/6000166622-what-data-can-i-upload-and-how-) accepted by [Figshare](https://figshare.com/), which is an online digital repository operated by Macmillan Publishers. You can create an account for free, and you will get a DOI when uploading files which you can then cite in your paper.

Comment: Fantastic! This is helpful. I will check this.

Comment: @xavier no problem - happy to help. :)

Comment: the "among the file types" link seems to be broken, perhaps this would work instead? https://help.figshare.com/article/item-types It mentions "audio or 3D representations" which suggests this might (or might not) be applicable to [Scientific paper with 3D scatterplot in supplementary information; I can add a video but how to let readers rotate/zoom interactively?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/184841/69206)

Answer (score 7):

Also have a look at [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org), a research data (including movies) and text repository operated by [CERN](http://home.cern) and [OpenAIRE](https://www.openaire.eu).

Like Figshare, Zenodo will generate a DOI for your publication.

Unlike Figshare, Zenodo is not owned by a big corporation.